# Is the place of “which clause” in this sentence correct?

Tags: relative-pronouns, clauses

I always have issues with using *which* clauses. I appreciate if someone could let me know if the *which* clause in the sentence below is correct.

> Something brings about unprecedented challenges to B **which** can be greatly alleviated by C.

The original sentences were:

> 1) Something brings about unprecedented challenges to B.
>   2) These challenges can be greatly alleviated by C.

Answer (score 1):

The "**relative clause**" is free to modify the previous noun, the 'noun to noun' noun phrase or even the whole previous phrase.

Example:

- **The bus** *for Zadar,* **which** *is usually very punctual, has been late.* - Here the non-defining relative clause refers to "**The bus (for Zadar)**" and not to "**Zadar**" as you can make from the context.

In most cases the reader is to determine what is being modified from the meaning of the sentence *(from the context)*. So, yes, the relative clause is correct in your example, but it could be that it's a non-defining relative clause whereupon you should place a comma before it.